# SVG <animate> offset from 0 not working

Tags: css, svg, offset, linear-gradients, svg-animate

The purpose of the animation is that fill background colour as loading battery. The solution seems to me apple gradient animation which shows as loading. But in the current SVG linearGradient animate not working when attribute `offset="0%"`

```css
div {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p><small>offset from 0%</small> <strong>not working</strong></p>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 110 88" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="mysvg">
    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
      <g id="Group" fill="#EAEAEA">
        <rect id="Brick-4" x="77.5" y="10" width="13.5" height="68" rx="3"></rect>
        <rect id="Brick-3" x="56" y="10" width="13.5" height="68" rx="3"></rect>
        <rect id="Brick-2" x="34.5" y="10" width="13.5" height="68" rx="3"></rect>
        <rect id="Brick-1" x="13" y="10" width="13.5" height="68" rx="3"></rect>
        <path d="M104,30.2724875 C104.164709,30.2576038 104.331485,30.25 104.5,30.25 C107.537566,30.25 110,32.7220822 110,35.7458573 L110,53.1708094 C110,56.2060875 107.531385,58.6666667 104.5,58.6666667 C104.331455,58.6666667 104.164681,58.6590557 104,58.6441617 L104,82.0033234 C104,85.3151964 101.311488,88 97.9970362,88 L6.0029638,88 C2.68761844,88 0,85.3182852 0,82.0033234 L0,5.99667663 C0,2.68480358 2.68851188,0 6.0029638,0 L97.9970362,0 C101.312382,0 104,2.68171476 104,5.99667663 L104,30.2724875 L104,30.2724875 Z M5,10.991014 C5,7.68226832 7.68678744,5 11.0051618,5 L92.9948382,5 C96.3113975,5 99,7.68493655 99,10.991014 L99,77.008986 C99,80.3177317 96.3132126,83 92.9948382,83 L11.0051618,83 C7.68860254,83 5,80.3150634 5,77.008986 L5,10.991014 Z"
        fill="url(#fromzero)
        "></path>
        <defs>
          <linearGradient id="fromzero" x1="0">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#4c7eaf"></stop>
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#828282"></stop>
            <animate attributeName="x1" dur="5s" from="0%" to="100%" repeatCount="indefinite" />
          </linearGradient>
        </defs>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
<div>
  <p><small>offset from 1%</small> <strong>working</strong></p>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 110 88" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="mysvg">
    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
      <g id="Group" fill="#EAEAEA">
        <rect id="Brick-4" x="77.5" y="10" width="13.5" height="68" rx="3"></rect>
        <rect id="Brick-3" x="56" y="10" width="13.5" height="68" rx="3"></rect>
        <rect id="Brick-2" x="34.5" y="10" width="13.5" height="68" rx="3"></rect>
        <rect id="Brick-1" x="13" y="10" width="13.5" height="68" rx="3"></rect>
        <path d="M104,30.2724875 C104.164709,30.2576038 104.331485,30.25 104.5,30.25 C107.537566,30.25 110,32.7220822 110,35.7458573 L110,53.1708094 C110,56.2060875 107.531385,58.6666667 104.5,58.6666667 C104.331455,58.6666667 104.164681,58.6590557 104,58.6441617 L104,82.0033234 C104,85.3151964 101.311488,88 97.9970362,88 L6.0029638,88 C2.68761844,88 0,85.3182852 0,82.0033234 L0,5.99667663 C0,2.68480358 2.68851188,0 6.0029638,0 L97.9970362,0 C101.312382,0 104,2.68171476 104,5.99667663 L104,30.2724875 L104,30.2724875 Z M5,10.991014 C5,7.68226832 7.68678744,5 11.0051618,5 L92.9948382,5 C96.3113975,5 99,7.68493655 99,10.991014 L99,77.008986 C99,80.3177317 96.3132126,83 92.9948382,83 L11.0051618,83 C7.68860254,83 5,80.3150634 5,77.008986 L5,10.991014 Z"
        fill="url(#fromone)
        "></path>
        <defs>
          <linearGradient id="fromone" x1="0">
            <stop offset="1%" stop-color="#4c7eaf"></stop>
            <stop offset="1%" stop-color="#828282"></stop>
            <animate attributeName="x1" dur="5s" from="0%" to="100%" repeatCount="indefinite" />
          </linearGradient>
        </defs>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chaning the code to this

```
<linearGradient id="fromzero" x1="0">
    <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#4c7eaf"></stop>
    <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#828282"></stop>
    <animate attributeName="x1" dur="5s" from="-100%" to="100%" repeatCount="indefinite" />
</linearGradient>
```

Makes the gradient split the background-color in the two colors, and moves it from -100% to 100%, making it possible to go from 0% to 100%, while giving it the exact same effect.

I've now also added the animation you wanted. It is being triggered by clicking on the `svg` element.

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9qc5th5z/1/) of the result

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your tweak solution. Do you think we can apply the animation when click on a button ?

Comment: Edited my answer. It is animated now

Comment: @Robert Longson yes I have seen it, unfortunately that doesn't work in safari & chrome  hope you have seen my comment in your answer

Comment: Yes but that's because Chrome/Safari have bugs with percentage based animations, they do support beginElement and beginElementAt